# $\sum_{j~\text{odd}} \sin(j/2 \pi x) \sin(j/2 \pi y) = 0$ for all $x \neq y $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Consider the formal series
$$
\sum_{j\geq 1} \sin\big(\frac{2j-1}{2} \pi x\big)\sin\big(\frac{2j-1}{2} \pi y\big),
$$
for $x \neq y$.

I evaluated this with Wolfram Alpha, and it returns 0 for this summation. Also, for $x =y$, the sum diverges.

Are these statements true, and if so, an intuitive explanation for this? Roughly speaking, I can see that as $j \to \infty$, the frequency of the sinusoids are increasing so that for a fixed $x, y$,the signs are changing frequently, so probably there is some "cancellation."

Comment: It is not true that $\sin(\frac{2j-1}{2} \pi x)^2 \to 1$. Indeed, for $x=2n,\, n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sin(\frac{2j-1}{2} \pi x)^2 = 0$ for all $j$. However, the sum does not exist in general. By which I mean if $f_n(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sin (\frac{2j-1}{2} \pi x)  \sin (\frac{2j-1}{2} \pi y)$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$ does not exist for every $x$, $y$.

Comment: I see. Regarding the first statement, now I am a bit confused. I agree with what you're saying, that $x = 2n$ gives an instance where $\phi_j^2(x) = 0$ for all $j$, $\phi_j(x) := \sin((2j - 1)/2 \pi x)$, however, at the same time, the period of $\phi_j$ is $4/ (2j - 1) \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$. What is happening?

Comment: What is happening is that you are trying to imagine the behavior of something that does not exist. The period may 'tend to zero as $j\to\infty$', but the actual limit of the function does not exist.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ integer numbers ?

Comment: No, they're reals.